# QNetworkAccessManager fails to execute correctly

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to implement  http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Creating_an_HTTP_network_request_in_Qt  and my code compiles without error but does not function. I have a warning that reply in "QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));"  is not being used.  I am sure this is my error and I am not setting up my HTTP GET correctly, but I am unsure of how to correct it.

//coreEng.h

```
#ifndef COREENG_H
#define COREENG_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class coreEng : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
        public:
            //coreEng(QObject);
            coreEng(QObject *parent = 0) :
                QObject(parent)
                {
                    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
                }

        private slots:

        public slots:
            void connect();
            void url(QNetworkReply *reply);
            void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply);
        private:
            QNetworkAccessManager* nam;
};

#endif // COREENG_H
```

//coreEng.cpp

```
"coreeng.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImageReader>

void coreEng::connect(){
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void coreEng::url(QNetworkReply*){
    QUrl url("http://www.nyctelecomm.com");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void coreEng::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply){

    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);

    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {

        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
        QImage pic = imageReader.read();

        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
        QString string(bytes); // string
    }

    else
    {

    }

    //delete reply();

}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "coreeng.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    coreEng mConnect;
    mConnect.connect();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Comment: @dbanet No packet ever leaves the NIC

Answer (score 0):

changed void coreEng::url(QNetworkReply*)  to  void coreEng::url()
changed  void url(QNetworkReply *reply);  to   void url();
added mConnect.url(); to main.cpp and I could see the http packet with wireshark exit the NIC and begin the session.